# What does matplotlib need to know about ffmpeg's installation

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

My installation of ffmpeg and matplotlib seem to be problematic:

```
In [9]: matplotlib.animation.writers["ffmpeg"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 ........
     58     def __getitem__(self, name):
     59         if not self.avail:
---> 60             raise RuntimeError("No MovieWriters available!")
     61         return self.avail[name]
     62 

RuntimeError: No MovieWriters available!
```

It looks like ffmpeg (or any other writer) has not been found. However, I have built it from source and installed it in `~/.local`. This is included in the `$PATH`, and I verified that the command `ffmpeg` is working from the terminal.

**Is there something I should watch out when installing ffmpeg?** Is there something else to do?

Config:

- Python 2.7.3
- matplotlib 1.2.0
- ffmpeg N-82786-gc188f35
- Red Hat 6.7

Note: I would like to avoid re-installing everything from scratch. I do not have root access and the only thing I installed manually is ffmpeg.

Comment: also, why do you expect the key "a" to return a valid writer?

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistake (just a test). The key should be "ffmpeg", but gives the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The writers checked for availabilty via  [the `isAvailable`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/animation.py#L359) class method which is more-or-less just checking is `popen` works.  The path it checks is the return value from the `bin_path` class method which by default looks for a class level attribute (supplied by the sub-classes) to specify which rcParams to look at for the path (the levels of indirection are worth it).

In the case of ffmpeg, this is `mpl.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']`.

```
In [33]: import matplotlib.animation as ma

In [34]: ma.FFMpegWriter.bin_path()
Out[38]: 
'ffmpeg'

In [39]: ma.FFMpegWriter.exec_key
Out[41]: 
'animation.ffmpeg_path'

In [42]: ma.FFMpegWriter.isAvailable()
Out[44]: 
True

In [45]: import matplotlib as mpl

In [46]: mpl.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']
Out[46]: 
'ffmpeg'

In [47]: mpl.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'jibberish'

In [48]: ma.FFMpegWriter.isAvailable()
Out[48]: 
False

In [49]: mpl.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'ffmpeg'

In [50]: ma.FFMpegWriter.isAvailable()
Out[50]: 
True
```